# Questions re: SMB Folders; Finder Background Color for subfolders

Tags: finder, smb, formatting

I am the only Mac user at a PC office, and I have to work with an SMB server from time to time. It's easier for me to copy the files from the SMB to my computer, do the work I need to do, then copy them back.

Is there a way to automatically format all Finder windows in a subfolder to have a different color, so I can tell when I'm working on a local version vs. the SMB version?

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't work well with multiple questions in a single post. You'd be best asking your second question as a distinctly separate post.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to set any background is to use icon view & set a colour or picture…
<sub>(Click for larger images)</sub>

[image] [image]

The only way to have it permeate down the hierarchy would be to set as default - but that will not constrain it to any given hierarchy, so you would be better to just set each manually, or create each top folder, set default; create the folder hierarchy, then repeat with another colour for another hierarchy.
Somewhat unwieldy, either way.